# How to set multiple chart.js min max value

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am rendering multiple chart.js on the view and after changed the data over a dropdown I want to update the options for the new Chart and for already created chart.

Well I will need to update the all charts dynamically and in my case the min and max values. I need the for all charts the same min and max value and after added a new it should update the maximum values. Is there any trick or so?

Here is and example: https://jsfiddle.net/xpalindromx/g1o6xcLb/

After the function

```
addChart(data, option, '1')
```

I am setting the min, max values and creating the second chart

```
 option.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = -3;
 option.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = 200;
 addChart(data, option, '2')
```

Now I need to update the min and max values of the FIRST chart as well

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please ?